# MySQL "exists" function in "where" clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select a field only if the field exists on the table. If it does not exist, then I want to select a different field in the "where" clause.

The use case for this is that I have several similar tables, some of which have a "user_id" field and others do not, but rather than hard-coding all the tables that have this, I want to just check for the existence of the field, so that I can use the same sql for all. Those that do not have user_id use the "id" field instead for my application.

This code gives me the error

> Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause'

for the table that does not have a user_id field.

I am using MySQL 5.7

```
select id from users 
    where 
        if ( 
            exists( select 1 from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'users' and column_name = 'user_id' ), 
                user_id > 10, 
                id > 10);
```

Comment: The error is that it doesnt know what / where user_id is;  Also, aren't you missing the THEN portion ? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/

Pretty sure the problem is a flaw in the logic of the if statement

Comment: I'm using the if function as described here: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php

Comment: Your idea doean't work. As the `users` table doesn't seem to have a `user_id`, the query is invalid, because it refers to that column. A query is parsed before it is run.

Comment: are you missing a closing ) ?

Comment: No you can't do that, you'll need *dynamic sql*

Comment: Guys, please look up the `IF` function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if. It is used correctly. The query is only invalid because of the column that doesn't exist in the table. As can be seen here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=914efa8211b327355e992d782007ae04

Comment: Still no need to use IF. Regular AND/OR are easier to optimize, and portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you're looking to do in the way you're looking to do it.

The interpreter has no expectation that you *might* only want to use one of these fields, and it correctly points out that one of them is not valid for that query.

I think you'd have a far easier time having a common field name for everything you're searching on.

Consider creating views that provide all the columns of the base table and map the varying column as user_id.

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW uniform_user 
AS
SELECT 
   id,
   id as user_id,
   ...
```

You can then exploit these views rather than the base tables and know that a user_id will definitely exist in each.

```
SELECT user_id FROM uniform_user
```

etc.